# are there too many parenthesis (brackets) in this boolean expression

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

im reading through a book covering boolean logic and ive come accross the following expression

```
(N AND ((M AND (W OR T)) OR (F AND (NOT W)))) OR B
```

are there two to many brackets, is it a typo?

Comment: 6 opening and 6 closing brackets. They are balanced, so no typo. Precedence might make some of them optional but it seems like a conscious decision to make it clear what needs to be evaluated when.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. The parenthesis are just used to ensure the precedence, that is, which expressions are going to be evaluated before the other expressions.

This is usefull when dealing with ANDs and ORs in the same expression (as in this expression). Using both ANDs and ORs together in the same expression can lead to unexpected results, so its a good practice to use parenthesis and though make explicit the evaluation order.